# MS Excel combine and sum on partial string matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 columns of information in Excel 2007/2010. I need to SUM the cost column, based on a partial string match in the debtor column, like this:

[image: original data]

Looks like:

[image: desired result]

NB: Ignore the possible difference in column width, etc.

I want Excel to pick up rows based on, for example, first 5 characters in the 1st column. Combine down to 1 row, and SUM the values next to them in the 2nd column.

Comment: Select The Data, Then from the data tab find 'SubTotal' see what options this gives you

Answer (score 0):

**Check the Screen Shot.**

[image]

The Formula I've used is,

```
=IF(E259=E260,"",SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(F259,ROW(F$259:F$269)-ROW(F259),,1)),--(E$259:E$269 = E259)))
```

**NB:** *Formula is in Cell G259. Where Text is in Column E and Numeric Values in Column F.*

*Alter the Data Range according to your Worksheet's situation.*

**Also note,** Your Output is SUBTOTAL which is not possible with SUMIF along with Partial Match. This Formula is considering each value as whole.

*Hope this help you.*